# Resize JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Sorry for ignorance, I'm a beginner. I'm trying to resize a `JFileChooser` so that it is the size of the screen resolution. To get the resolution I used the following code:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

I have searched, but I could not find how to effectively change the size of `JFileChooser`. I tested some solutions that I found, but they did not work.

Comment: Consider `JFrame. MAXIMIZED_BOTH`; add the `JFileChooser` to a panel having `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (note the comments) :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileChooserFrame extends JFrame {

    public FileChooserFrame() {//construct a JFrame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //maximize to full screen

        //constract japnel. apply a border layout manager to it
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(mainPanel); //add panel to frame

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); //construct file chooser
        mainPanel.add(fc, BorderLayout.CENTER); //add it to panel
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new FileChooserFrame();
    }
}
```

If no other components need to be added to the frame, you can add the file-chooser directly to the frame (not recommended) :

```
public FileChooserFrame() {//construct a JFrame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //maximize to full screen
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); //construct file chooser
    add(fc); //add file chooser to frame
    setVisible(true);
}
```